# Copy data from 3 workbooks to 1 master

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with my code to copy data from 3 workbooks with same worksheet name to one master workbook also having the same name. The main problem is to define the last row. After I copy the first data set from the first workbook and then go to second one I want to paste the data below the first data in master workbook and so on. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Below is my unfinished code:

```
Sub refresh()
Dim wball, wb1, wb2, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws, sht As Worksheet
Dim wbpath As String
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wbpath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
'wball = ThisWorkbook 'master workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'clears master wb
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
    ws.Rows(3).ClearContents
    'ws.Rows("3:" & LastRow).Delete
    ws.Range("Tab").Delete

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(wbpath & "\file1.xlsm")
LastRow = wb1.Sheets("Tab").Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A3:CD" & LastRow).Value = wb1.Sheets("Tab").Range("A3:CD" & LastRow).Value

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(wbpath & "\file2.xlsm")
LastRow = wb2.Sheets("Tab").Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'ws.
ws.Range("A3:CD" & LastRow).Value = wb2.Sheets("Tab").Range("A3:CD" & LastRow).Value

wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Ok, I have made some changes and everything is working now as it should be.

```
Sub refresh()
    Dim masterwb As Workbook
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wb3 As Workbook
    Dim masterws As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbpath As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRowSource As Long
    Dim LastRowDestination As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    wbpath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    'masterwb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'clears master wb
    Set masterws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab")
    'LastRow = masterws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        masterws.Rows(3).ClearContents
        masterws.Range("A4:CD9999").Delete


'start to copy data from 3 workbooks
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(wbpath & "\file1.xlsm")
    LastRowDestination = wb1.Sheets("Tab").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    masterws.Range("A3:CD" & LastRowDestination).Value = wb1.Sheets("Tab").Range("A3:CD" & LastRowDestination).Value

    LastRowSource = masterws.Cells(masterws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'LastRowSource + LastRowDestination -3 because im getting 3 extra rows with #N/D
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(wbpath & "\file2.xlsm")
    LastRowDestination = wb2.Sheets("Tab").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    masterws.Range("A" & LastRowSource & ":CD" & LastRowSource + LastRowDestination -3).Value = wb2.Sheets("Tab").Range("A3:CD" & LastRowDestination).Value

    LastRowSource = masterws.Cells(masterws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(wbpath & "\file3.xlsm")
    LastRowDestination = wb3.Sheets("Tab").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    masterws.Range("A" & LastRowSource & ":CD" & LastRowSource + LastRowDestination -3).Value = wb3.Sheets("Tab").Range("A3:CD" & LastRowDestination).Value


    wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wb3.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. If you don't see the errors you cannot fix them. If you don't fix them your code doesn't work. • Remove `On Error Resume Next` and fix your errors first. • Then note that `Dim ws, sht As Worksheet` only declares `sht As Worksheet` but `ws As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim ws As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet`. • Fix all this and update ([edit]) your question.

Comment: To solve your issue you need to distinguish between `LastRowSource` and `LastRowDestination` one is the last row of your source file and the other of your destination file, this should help you I think. Give it a try.